# Experience documentation about Shared Nothing Architecture

Tags: architecture, shared-nothing

Do you have any experience of designing a Real Shared-Nothing Architecture?
Would you have some readings to recommend me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Building Scalable Web Sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356) by [Flickr](http://flickr.com) architect [Cal Henderson](http://www.iamcal.com/) is pretty much the holy book for scalable web architectures.

The [presentations](http://danga.com/words/) by [Brad Fitzpatrick](http://bradfitz.com/) of [Danga Interactive](http://danga.com), creators of LiveJournal, are also excellent case studies. Check out [this one](http://danga.com/words/2007_06_usenix/usenix.pdf) first.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [The J2EE guy still doesn’t get PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/07/01/the-j2ee-guy-still-doesnt-get-php/) is (still) worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just study and think about the concept of **stateless beans**, and then apply it to web app programming. On the server side you have stateless JSON channels, on client you have all state including authorization token. Server need only to verify this token, which is included in every JSON request.

I've designed and written once fully AJAX application without using HTTP sessions. In fact I was then a beginner and didn't know that it is called **Shared-Nothing Architecture** :) I've done good just with my invention, without any readings. But maybe I should describe my experiences in details for other people...